# MagicalRecord is deleting all the created objects each time app loads

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm not quite sure what's going on but every time my app loads in the iOS simulator the data that was persisted in my app with MagicalRecord is being deleted & recreated. Perhaps this means the data isn't being persisted?

I have no idea what's going on.  In my app delegate I have:

```
[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed:@"HFDatabase.sqlite"];
```

In my didFinishLaunching... method as well as `[MagicalRecord cleanUp];` in applicationWillTerminate method. The log is also outputting the following:

```
Context DEFAULT is about to save. Obtaining permanent IDs for new 20 inserted objects
```

Which I assume means the data is being saved. Yet it recreates the data every time. Any ideas?

**Update**

It appears as though it simply deletes the database each time I rebuild the app. Is that supposed to happen? Any way to stop that from happening?

Comment: That should not happen. - Do you have any code that creates some initial database (or copies it from the app bundle)? Perhaps that code overwrites an existing database.

Comment: All I have is a single datamodel file.

Comment: @MartinR it appears as though I needed to call `saveNestedContexts` however that method is being deprecated. Not sure what the best practice is now.

Answer (score 2):

From your comments it looks like you were missing a save method.  Do `[localContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];` after your changes.